# C++ datastructure (standard library) dump (like the python print function)

Tags: c++, data-structures, recursion, recursive-datastructures

When I'm programming in python it's very convenient to just print whatever datastructure you want to inspect on the screen. Does there exist something like this in C++ for STL datastructures?

It should recurse on the contents of the datastructure and print it with some specific layout for sets, maps, pairs, ..

Comment: Some debuggers have knowledge of the standard library classes, but you can't really inspect data structures of C++ classes unless you have an intimate knowledge of the compiler and class library. C++ doesn't have the introspection facilities dynamic language like Python have.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pretty-print C++ STL containers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4850473/pretty-print-c-stl-containers)

Comment: Bear in mind that Python requires you to write a `__str__()` or `__repr__()` function for your class in order for it to print out as something other than `<Spam object at 0x12345678>`. C++ requires you to overload `ostream& operator<<(ostream&, T)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4850473/pretty-print-c-stl-containers) and [here](http://louisdx.github.com/cxx-prettyprint/) for pretty printing standard library containers.